# Call Groups Video in WebRTC

Tags: ios, swift, webrtc

I am working with webRTC to make group video calls. I have obtained audio from Remote (already streaming between devices) but the problem I am having is that all devices do not receive each other's video, thanks

Does H264, VP8 and VP9 affect my project?

Comment: in group calls, there is a mesh networking which makes even impossible call impossible after 4-5 people. So that you may need to use server for that. Ant Media Server may help you. It supports groups call via WebRTC. https://antmedia.io

Comment: @faraway OP never said that he wanted to have calls between hundreds of people. OP's issue is that the devices do not receive each other's video. mesh is fine in many scenarios.

Comment: @Daljeet the service that you are advertising charges per minute ... why would OP use that, and how does that solve OP's issue ?

Comment: Then could you let us see some of your code snippets? Generally browsers choose the correct encoder in signaling phase. So I don't think H264, VP8 and VP9 cause a problem on your side.

Comment: i am voting to close this unless you can provide some code for us to look at

Answer (score -1):

[enter image description here][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hjp4L.png**strong text**

Create a `RTCPeerConnection` using that.

Answer (score -1):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8SPOi.png)

lets start the connection by adding a local stream to it.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ntuym.png)

setdescription and add icecandidate  for remote and local